# Date selection with separate boxes for day, month and year

Tags: date, jsf-2, drop-down-menu, custom-component

I'm making a Java EE + EJB + JSF web app and I'd like to have 3 select boxes for date of birth(1 for day, 1 for month and 1 for year) in my registration form just like on Facebook.

Of course selected date needs to be valid, so for example if someone chooses February 2009, the range of days to choose has to be only 1-28.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Your question is quite broad but in a nutshell, what you'll need is a  A custom JSF validator ([simple tutorial](http://www.mkyong.com/jsf2/custom-validator-in-jsf-2-0/)) is designed exactly for your use case. You might find your work a bit easier by using a component framework like primefaces,richfaces or open faces

Comment: @kolossus: better would be to just ajax-update the day dropdown when month dropdown is changed. This way you don't need a validator. PrimeFaces/RichFaces/OpenFaces have as far as I see no such day/month/year multidropdown component. They've only a calendar popup component.

Comment: AjMeen: this is a too broad question. Show some relevant code and tell us where exactly you're stucking while implementing the requirement. It is just the presenting valid days on change of month?

Comment: @BalusC
Well, to be honest I thought that there is a ready for use component to do that. But if there is not - all I have to do is 'hardcode' values to select (days,months,years) and create some logic which will be changing days range for specific months/years?

Comment: The canonical way for that is a calendar popup. Basically all component libraries provide this.

Comment: I noticed that there is calendar popup, but I would like to use comboboxes as I mentioned in my question. And to achieve that all I have to do is what I said in the previous comment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would consider using a component library for this purpose. To avoid implementing all validations-checks by myself. The major jsf-component libraries have things similar to what you want.

[Here](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/calendarTime.jsf) is a primefaces example of a component that comes close to what you want.

and [here](http://showcase.richfaces.org/richfaces/component-sample.jsf?demo=calendar&skin=blueSky) is a richfaces example